# How do you play this part?

Tags: guitar, learning, performing, tablature

There's a capo on 4 but I'm still having trouble playing this part:

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulty with, the stretch?  Do you have smaller hands?

Comment: I think there's some mistake or incorrect tabbing...

Comment: This is non-sense. Note that the two lowest notes are identical, so you can leave out the note on the low E string and just play the two perfect fifths on A, d, and g. Where's that tab from?

Comment: It's impossible unless you are a freak of nature and have fingers as long as your arms.

Comment: I think more context is needed for a useful answer. What music is this?  Where can we look at the full score? Clearly, as others have stated, there is something wrong with this example.

Answer (score 1):

Both the fretted 6th fret on the E String, and the fretted note at the 1st fret are exactly the same, therefore just don't play that note, unless you have an eight inch long little finger.

Answer (score 0):

AS E & A not strummed put capo on 5

[image: Chord]